# How to silently install Chrome or is there a portable version?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, portability, offline, chromium

**Read first please:** This solution is intended for a limited amount of elder users and they certainly care more about installing "another thing" than about a silent installation (they don't even trust the internet and don't use it) and also they are fully aware that I will save that process for them; yes, I told them and they agreed. If you have a better solution, please share it with me.

**Now the question:** I need to silently install/copy Google Chrome in a Windows computer without internet, while installing another offline web application of mine provided in a CD. Is there any reliable portable version of Chrome?

In other words: I need to save the chrome installation process to the users, so they only need to execute a single installer.

**Extra info:** I'm currently using http://www.advancedinstaller.com/ to generate the installer.

Thank you.

Comment: A great way to get them to trust the internet is to start silently installing stuff.

Comment: @MitchDempsey I asked for a better solution if you have it, your sarcasm is not useful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Chrome Portable http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable